# Trending hot and popular topics in an application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a simple mobile app, backend is made up of Node.JS and MongoDB (Mongoose) and express.
My app has **topics** with fields such as:

> _id, title, subtitle, details,...,tags[ ], **viewCount, likeCount, shareCount, commentsCount,** updatedAt, createdAt

Now I want to find **trending topics** (topics that are currently hot and popular) mainly based on viewCount, likeCount, shareCount, commentsCount (other suggestions are welcome)

Currently I am using the following formula:

```
popularity = viewCount * 1 + likeCount * 2 + shareCount * 2 + commentsCount * 3
```

But this is foolish, as it does not take into account the main goal of trending which is **current (now)**

Any suggestion on how to improve my formula to get the desired results.

*Note: I am willing to add or modify fields in my database*

Answer (score 0):

This is what i finally came up with

```
popularity = 
(viewCount * 1 + likeCount * 2 + shareCount * 2 + commentsCount * 3) / actionTimestamp
```

where actionTimestamp is updated every time when one of the following is updated viewCount, likeCount, shareCount, commentsCount

I know this is not solid, any help is appriciated